# Duplicate every nth row but replace one column value with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that look like this

```
          x      y Year          LandCover       value                                             UniqueIdentifier
 1: 126949.6 914890 2013             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 2: 126949.6 914890 2015             Arable 0.008080324             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 3: 126949.6 914890 2017             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 4: 126949.6 914890 2018             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 5: 126949.6 914890 2019             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 6: 126949.6 914890 2020             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 7: 126949.6 914890 2021             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
 8: 126949.6 914890 2013 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
 9: 126949.6 914890 2015 Broadleaf woodland 0.179682687 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
10: 126949.6 914890 2017 Broadleaf woodland 0.038091846 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
11: 126949.6 914890 2018 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
12: 126949.6 914890 2019 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
```

The column 'Year' has 7 unique values that repeat for every unique combination of columns 'x', 'y' and 'LandCover' (also present as a concatenated string in the column 'UniqueIdentifier'). I want to insert a row for every missing 'Year' between those seven values - that is a row after every Year == 2013, and after Year == 2015. The new rows will have identical values for the remaining columns 'x', 'y', 'Landcover' and 'UniqueIdentifier', but new values for the 'Year' column - that is values 2014 and 2016 respectively, and NA for the column 'value'

So the above example of 12 rows will have 16 rows when processed for what I want:

```
          x      y Year          LandCover       value                                             UniqueIdentifier
1  126949.6 914890 2013             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
2  126949.6 914890 2014             Arable          NA             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
3  126949.6 914890 2015             Arable 0.008080324             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
4  126949.6 914890 2016             Arable          NA             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
5  126949.6 914890 2017             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
6  126949.6 914890 2018             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
7  126949.6 914890 2019             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
8  126949.6 914890 2020             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
9  126949.6 914890 2021             Arable 0.000000000             126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable
10 126949.6 914890 2013 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
11 126949.6 914890 2014 Broadleaf woodland          NA 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
12 126949.6 914890 2015 Broadleaf woodland 0.179682687 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
13 126949.6 914890 2016 Broadleaf woodland          NA 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
14 126949.6 914890 2017 Broadleaf woodland 0.038091846 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
15 126949.6 914890 2018 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
16 126949.6 914890 2019 Broadleaf woodland 0.000000000 126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland
```

I know of na_approx() from dplyr; and is.regular() from zoo - but they both work only when NAs are present - I cannot figure out how to add the NAs to begin with. ANy help would be much appreciated.

Here is a reproducible dataset:

```
dput(jnk28)
structure(list(x = c(126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 
126949.587950801, 126949.587950801, 126949.587950801), y = c(914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 914890.037425214, 
914890.037425214), Year = c("2013", "2015", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020", "2021", "2013", "2015", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", 
"2021", "2013", "2015", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", 
"2013", "2015", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2013", 
"2015", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2013", "2015", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2013", "2015", "2017", 
"2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2013"), LandCover = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L), levels = c("Broadleaf woodland", "Coniferous woodland", 
"Arable", "Improved grassland", "Semi-natural grassland", "Mountain, heath and bog", 
"Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Coastal", "Built-up gardens"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0.00808032415807247, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.179682686924934, 
    0.0380918458104134, 0, 0, 0, 1.2629359960556, 0.048693586140871, 
    0.0127272941172123, 0, 0.010975711978972, 0, 0.0381818823516369, 
    0.0129696354269981, 0.790930449962616, 1.05838894844055, 
    1.3420113325119, 1.17148506641388, 1.1884298324585, 1.16333484649658, 
    1.5163232088089, 0.967662692070007, 0.48012962937355, 0.211137503385544, 
    0.313463360071182, 0.206228896975517, 0.732346892356873, 
    0.587746262550354, 3.06972241401672, 2.85024571418762, 3.02812576293945, 
    3.05821418762207, 3.04066801071167, 3.04260468482971, 3.05358028411865, 
    0.538379609584808, 4.13329887390137, 4.46173000335693, 4.40838718414307, 
    4.22813367843628, 5.19888973236084, 5.36220264434814, 73.6505737304688
    ), UniqueIdentifier = c("126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Arable", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Broadleaf woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Built-up gardens", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coastal", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Coniferous woodland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Freshwater", "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Improved grassland", 
    "126949.587950801_and_914890.037425214_and_Mountain, heath and bog"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55ee01224650>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using:

```
jnk29 <- jnk28 %>%
    complete(nesting(UniqueIdentifier), Year = full_seq(Year, period = 1), fill = list(value = NA)) %>%
    fill(x,y,LandCover,UniqueIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

example_data$Year <- factor(example_data$Year,
                      levels=as.character(2013:2021))

complete(example_data,Year) |> 
  fill(everything(),
       .direction = "down")
```